# Not able to update UI in windows form

Tags: winforms, user-interface, thread-safety

I have one windows form in which I have a number of images shown using delegate. When one event is fired I need to remove image and put label saying image not shown. I have created new thread to update UI. My problem is for 8 image my event is called 8 times. But label is coming for only 4 or 5 labels only. Can anyone help me with this error? Or suggest any new way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I write down label.bringtofront() , it did solve my problem. And now it is coming in all label.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across similar issue and the simplest solution was to add `Thread.Sleep(10)` between each process.

So in your case you would add `Thread.Sleep(10)` between each image update. You would want to try other values, I was starting with 50 but found that 10 had the same effect.

I know it will increase your application runtime but for small processing like yours it's fair enough (only 80 ms).